# How do I process several lists at once?

Tags: python-3.x, multithreading, multiprocessing

I have a big list of numbers. I want to split that big list of numbers into x number of lists and process them in parallel.

Here's the code that I have so far:

```
from multiprocessing import Pool
import numpy

def processNumList(numList):
    for num in numList:
        outputList.append(num ** 2)

numThreads = 5

bigNumList = list(range(50))

splitNumLists = numpy.array_split(bigNumList, numThreads)

outputList = []

for numList in splitNumLists:
    processNumList(numList)

print(outputList)
```

The above code does the following:

- Splits a big list of numbers into the specified number of smaller lists
- Passes each of those lists to the processNumList function
- Prints the result list afterwards

Everything there works as expected, but it only processes one list at a time. I want every list to be processed simultaneously.

What is the proper code to do that? I experimented with `pool` but could never seem to get it working.

Comment: Do you expect `outputList` to have ordered result items (in their initial order) ?

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest - In this case, no. I'm just trying to get a working example, so the order of the resulting list doesn't matter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the code I ended up using.

I used `threading.Thread()` to process the lists asynchronously and then called `thread.join()` to ensure that all of the threads were finished before moving on.

I added `time.sleep` for demonstration purposes (to simulate a lengthy task), but obviously you wouldn't want to use that in production code.

```
import numpy
import threading
import time

def process_num_list(numList):
    for num in numList:
        output_list.append(num ** 2)
        time.sleep(1)

num_threads = 5

big_num_list = list(range(30))

split_num_lists = numpy.array_split(big_num_list, num_threads)

output_list = []

threads = []

for num_list in split_num_lists:
    thread = threading.Thread(target=process_num_list, args=[num_list])
    threads.append(thread)
    thread.start()

for thread in threads:
    thread.join()

print(output_list)
```

---

As a bonus, here's a working example of five Selenium windows:

```
from selenium import webdriver
import numpy
import threading
import time

def scrapeSites(siteList):
    print("Preparing to scrape " + str(len(siteList)) + " sites")
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path = r"..\chromedriver.exe")
    driver.set_window_size(700, 400)
    for site in siteList:
        print("\nNow scraping " + site)
        driver.get(site)
        pageTitles.append(driver.title)
    driver.quit()

numThreads = 5

fullWebsiteList = ["https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Special:Random"] * 30

splitWebsiteLists = numpy.array_split(fullWebsiteList, numThreads)

pageTitles = []

threads = []

for websiteList in splitWebsiteLists:
    thread = threading.Thread(target=scrapeSites, args=[websiteList])
    threads.append(thread)
    thread.start()

for thread in threads:
    thread.join()

print(pageTitles)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this:

```
import threading

class MyClass(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self):
        # init stuff

    def run(self, arg, arg2):
        # your logic to process the list

# split the list as you already did
for _ in range(numThreads):
    MyThread(arg, arg2).start()
```